# (C++) Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

Visual Studio is for some weird reason showing me this error and keep saying that count is not const int while trying to initialised array. Check image.

[Error: expression must have a constant value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2i0X.png)
[image]

This is function call at main:

```
std::string fileName("shows.tv");
const int COUNT = 10;
Episode** episodes = loadEpisodesFromFile(fileName, COUNT);
```

and this is function declaration at header file:

```
Episode** loadEpisodesFromFile(std::string, const int);
```

I don't get it. Variable count is already declared as const int but it's not working.

Comment: `Episode* episodes[count];` this is the actual error line, where `count` is a function parameter, this is what you should highlight in the question

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] reproducing that problem as required here please!

Comment: Not totally sure on this, but do you maybe have another variable defined as "count" as a global that this might be getting confused with?

Comment: The error saying `constant value` doesn't refer to the same thing as a `const` variable. It needs to be known at compile time. Use a `std::vector` to allocate dynamic arrays.

Comment: I don't have any global variables. It's school task we are not allowed to use `std::vector`

Comment: The compiler is correct. `count` must be a compile time constant. `c++` does not support VLAs.

Comment: Is the value of count changed anywhere in your code?

Comment: Another problem is even if `c++` allowed this you would be returning a pointer to a variable that no longer exists.

Comment: ***It's school task we are not allowed to use `std::vector`*** then you must use `new` instead of `Episode* episodes[count]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Episode* episodes[count]` is not valid because **count** is a parameter from the function 
**loadEpisodesFromFile** which is unknown at compiling time...

you need to use an std::vector instead

```
std::vector<Episode*> episodes(count);
```